# How can I subscribe to a promise using rx.js?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a function that returns promise.
I want to subscribe to that promise using rx.js in such way that calling of this function will push notifications to all subscribers.

Here is what I have:

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();

var subscription = subject.subscribe(
    function (x) { console.log('onNext: ' + x); },
    function (e) { console.log('onError: ' + e.message); },
    function () { console.log('onCompleted'); }
);

//here I want to push first notification
subject.fromPromise(functionThatReturnsPromise()); 

//some code

//here I want to push second notification
subject.fromPromise(functionThatReturnsPromise());
```

As a result subscriber receives only one notification.

How to solve that?

Answer (score 7):

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();

var subscription = subject.mergeAll().subscribe(
    function (x) { console.log('onNext: ' + x); },
    function (e) { console.log('onError: ' + e.message); },
    function () { console.log('onCompleted'); }
);

subject.onNext(Rx.Observable.fromPromise(functionThatReturnsPromise()));

//some code

subject.onNext(Rx.Observable.fromPromise(functionThatReturnsPromise()));
```

The subject here is now a metastream (an observable of observables). And before subscribing to it, we "flatten" it by calling `mergeAll()`. On the `onNext()` we are feeding Observables to the subject, that's what makes it a metastream.

Comment: Note that the order of promises resolution may be important here. While dealing with similar problem two key points was to use `mergeAll(1)` to limit concurrency and also use `Observable.defer()` instead of `Observable.fromPromise()` to ensure that possible promise chain will be executed in one go. More details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815109/order-of-execution-for-rxjs-observable-from-chained-promises